# Is it possible to return a type or interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript

What I want is to return a interface, not a variable with the interface type. For example:

```
Interface A{}

function f1(){
    return A;
}
```

Comment: Interfaces don't exist at runtime. They only exist at compile-time. So no.

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid this is not possible, because interfaces do not exist at runtime.

What you are asking for would be in the domain of a theoretical reflection/type-introspection system injected into the Javascript runtime environment by the TypeScript compiler, perhaps with the returned interface converted to a runtime accessible metadata information object, but no such thing exists at this time.

The closest we have currently is constructor-information for some decorators (properties, parameters, classes), but that's different.